Difference of consecutive constant powers
Let $a = n$ and $b = n + 1$ for some positive integer $n$.

power 1: $b^1 - a^1 = 1$
power 2: $b^2 - a^2 = a + b$
power 3: $b^3 - a^3 = 1 + 3ab$

Is there a generalization for the result of $b^k - a^k$ for all positive integers $k > 3$ where the difference can be calculated in my head? For example, for $99^2 - 98^2$, I cannot calculate the squared values in my head, but I can add $99$ to $98$ to get $197$.

Yes there is. $$a^k-b^k=(a-b)(\sum_{r=0}^{k-1} a^{k-r-1}b^r),k≥1,k\in \mathbb{Z}$$

Hi @Gwen, please don't answer in the comments!

@SammyBlack I thought it was a bit trivial hence I did that. You've already given the answer. Thanks for that.

Also OP I gave a general answer. For your specific value, $b-a=1$, so that can be applied in my expression.

The only thing i have in mind is to use Newton's formula
$$
(A+B)^k=\sum_{\ell =0}^{k}\frac{k!}{\ell !\,(k-\ell)!}A^{k-\ell}B^{\ell}
$$
Now, in our case,
$$
b^k-a^k=(n+1)^k-n^k=\left(\sum_{\ell =0}^{k}\frac{k!}{\ell !\,(k-\ell)!}n^{k-\ell}\right) - n^k
$$
and since for $\ell =0$ we get $n^k$, we have that
$$
(n+1)^k-n^k=\sum_{\ell=1}^{k}\frac{k!}{\ell !\,(k-\ell)!}n^{k-\ell}
$$
Indeed you can check that this formula generalizes wht you have found for $k=1,2,3.$

Yes, but there are many patterns and it's not clear which you prefer.
By the Binomial Theorem,
$$
(n + 1)^k = \sum_{i=0}^k \binom{k}{i}n^i, 
$$
so after subtracting off the highest power of $n$,
$$
(n + 1)^k - n^k = \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \binom{k}{i}n^i, 
$$
where the binomial coefficients come from row $k$ of Pascal's triangle, and we have dropped the final $1$.
Also, we can factor a difference of $k$th powers:
$$
b^k - a^k = (b - a)(b^{k-1} + ab^{k-2} + \cdots + a^{k-2}b + a^{k-1}), 
$$
and since $b - a = 1$, we get the formula
$$
b^k - a^k = b^{k-1} + ab^{k-2} + \cdots + a^{k-2}b + a^{k-1}. 
$$
There are also formulas using finite differences with rising and/or falling factorials. Without specifying more about the form of the expression you're looking for, it's impossible to narrow it down further. Hopefully, some of these formulas here in this answer and in the links provided will help you in your search, and perhaps you will come back with a more specific question about differences of powers.

I really like your profile picture. Is this inspired from any cartoon character or something related?

Haha, thanks. No, it was just me messing around with a filter many years ago, looking like an early twentieth century newsie. :-)
